# Will the real serial downvoter please stand up?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

I guess someone is peeved at me, but doesn't have the courage to reveal themselves.

-2  17:36   downvote    My boss gave me everyone's pay by mistake and mine is lower, how can I increase it?

-2  17:36   downvote    Should I tell my co-workers that branch manager uses drugs (crack) at the office?

-2  17:35   downvote    Addressing burnout when applying for a new job

-2  17:34   downvote    Convincing my manager to let me work from home

-2  17:33   downvote    My facebook wall is bothering some colleagues at work, do they have the right?

-2  17:31   downvote    What could happen if I ignore or disobey HR while getting fired?

-2  8 hours ago     2 events     How to get external feedback for improving one's programming style/work habits

-2  8 hours ago     downvote    Is it appropriate to ask about a company's dress code during an interview?

-2  8 hours ago     downvote    What to do after being passed over for a promotion

-2  1 hour ago  downvote    'Thanks' for a raise? How to reply?

**Some answers quite old.... But not a single comment...**

Comment: The odds are pretty good that those votes will be reversed in a few hours.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - the reversals are getting reversed. Someone here is sick: 10 / -2  6 mins ago  2 events   How to get external feedback for improving one's programming style
-2  17 mins ago  downvote  Is it appropriate to ask about a company's dress code during an interview?
-2  18 mins ago

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Serial downvoters are cowards and decidely unprofessional. They should be expunged from this site:state your case and suffer the consequences or just move on. Taking the coward's way out doesn't help anyone but the warped ego of a down-voter. Down-votes should come with greater penalty: Perhaps a percentage of your present score - that would give high rep members pause before engaging on a campaign of such behavior. They way it is now, one point, or even ten points, is insignificant to a member with a 10k rep, but quite significant to someone with a rep of 300 - simple math.

Comment: Is your goal to ostracize yourself from everyone here? To come across as childish? Grow up.

Comment: @Vector "They should be expunged from this site" -- and maybe ranters too?  I tried to help you and came on this morning to a pile of...something in response.  You are ascribing characteristics and motives without evidence, you are assuming that no downvote you receive is ever deserved (it must be the cowardly downvoter!), and you act as if being upset grants you license to lash out.  Your current behavior does not inspire people to be sympathetic, so if you're really trying to understand and address a problem, you might want to step away for a while and try again later.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - One of the funniest comments I've seen in a while...

Comment: @enderland - Yes, you've articulated my goals perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - _you are assuming that no downvote you receive is ever deserved_ - yes, that's it! I get to down-vote everybody, nobody can down-vote me! BTW - _a pile of...something in response_ - where is exactly is the "..."? Care to specify? I delivered some criticism - do you consider all criticism to be "..."? "Pot calling the kettle black"?

Comment: @MonicaCellio -2 8 hours ago 2 events How to get external feedback for improving one's programming style/work habits

-2 8 hours ago downvote Is it appropriate to ask about a company's dress code during an interview?

-2 8 hours ago downvote What to do after being passed over for a promotion

-2 1 hour ago downvote 'Thanks' for a raise? How to reply?

_All in my imagination?_ Or are we are **BOTH** encouraging someone....

Comment: @MonicaCellio  _does not inspire people to be sympathetic_ - my goal in this question was not to  "inspire people to be sympathetic". Note the title.

Comment: You say *"We're all adults here"* in a comment to shog's answer below but all I can see from you in this question is a bunch of whining that wouldn't look out of place on the most emo corner of livejournal. You've been downvoted. Some of those votes are not deserved. I get it. We've *all* been there. It might suck but they're only make-believe internet points anyway, so move on.

Comment: It appears that the problem is that in general your answers are not that good...  Its nothing personal you got a few more downvotes from me as I looked at this. again nothing personal.  Only one of your answers was deserving of an upvote in my opinion.  Lots of them deserved a downvote.  More than I bothered to vote on.

Answer (score 23):

> But not a single comment... are you afraid of getting your ears boxed again?

Why would you say that? Are you in the habit of engaging in long, argumentative discussions with folks who comment on your posts?

If so, then you have your answer. Why bother commenting if it's just gonna make you defensive and nasty? If you want folks to offer constructive feedback, you have to be willing to accept it.

Also, please read: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: -1: I don't have a problem with "constructive feedback". What I do have a problem with is getting flamed because I speak my mind. If someone "offends" I have the **right** to "defend".  _Are you in the habit of engaging in long, argumentative discussions with folks who comment on your posts?_ I don't engage in " long, argumentative discussions" on this site. But I do **not** pull punches. I play clean but tough. "We're all adults here".

Comment: _if it's just gonna make you_ : **gonna** is not word I'm familiar with. Please explain - I thought this was an English language site....

Comment: gonna is slang for going to. The nice thing about being native or bilingual in a language is you know exactly what rules to break.